# Change underline Material UI Autocomplete animation

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, autocomplete, material-ui

I am using a Material UI Autocomplete component in my project ( the "Faculdade" field ). However the animation/transition when I focus on this component consists on spreading from the middle out. I want the animation to be like the "Password" field. From the left to the right. But I do not know how can I change this. Does anyone know?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have prior experience with that specific library, but from a quick glimpe it looks like all you need to do is modify the `left` and the `transform-origin` props of the 2nd `hr` tag and you're good to go .

```
  left: 0px;
  transform-origin: left center;
```

quick example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-my-formsy-materialui-5setmg?file=style.css